# `GITHUB_PULL_REQUEST_BASE_REF: parameter null or not set` error in github actions

Tags: github-actions, sqlfluff

I am getting this error while trying to set a github actions. My goal is to set up a github actions that uses another template for linting and fixing SQL. Here is my github folder.[image: github folder structure]
The models folder contains a single sql file (with `.sql` file extention). The content of the sql folder is an sql file `testing.sql` with the query: `select a,b,c, document as doc from table`.

The workflow file contains the following yml file:

```
on:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  test-check:
    name: runner / sqlfluff (github-check)
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: yu-iskw/action-sqlfluff@v3
        id: lint-sql
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
          reporter: github-pr-review
          sqlfluff_version: "1.2.0"
          sqlfluff_command: "fix" # Or "lint"
          config: "${{ github.workspace }}/.sqlfluff"
          paths: '${{ github.workspace }}/models'
      - name: 'Show outputs (Optional)'
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo '${{ steps.lint-sql.outputs.sqlfluff-results }}' | jq -r '.'
          echo '${{ steps.lint-sql.outputs.sqlfluff-results-rdjson }}' | jq -r '.'
```

The `.sqlfluff` file contains a default configuration from the following site: [sqlfulff](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html#builtin-macro-blocks).

The workflow run is throwing the following error which I couldn't quite figure out: [image: output error]

I don't know what the  `line 15: GITHUB_PULL_REQUEST_BASE_REF: parameter null or not set` means in the error. I would be glad if anyone can help with the error.

Answer (score 3):

It is a parameter used by [yu-iskw/action-sqlfluff `action.yml`](https://github.com/yu-iskw/action-sqlfluff/blob/68793370e661f6240cd4ea398a13ccc3392a0c6b/action.yml#L149-L175) in its [`entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/yu-iskw/action-sqlfluff/blob/cd06010153713d470d5c2841ee9fc584a3c7b53a/entrypoint.sh#L15).

```bash
SQL_FILE_PATTERN="${FILE_PATTERN:?}"
SOURCE_REFERENCE="origin/${GITHUB_PULL_REQUEST_BASE_REF:?}"
changed_files=$(git diff --name-only --no-color "$SOURCE_REFERENCE" "HEAD" -- "${SQLFLUFF_PATHS:?}" |
  grep -e "${SQL_FILE_PATTERN:?}" |
  xargs -I% bash -c 'if [[ -f "%" ]] ; then echo "%"; fi' || :)
```

Set it to the remote branch parameter `github_base_ref` you want to compare to (`main` for instance).

In your case:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  test-check:
    name: runner / sqlfluff (github-check)
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: yu-iskw/action-sqlfluff@v3
        id: lint-sql
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
          reporter: github-pr-review
          sqlfluff_version: "1.2.0"
          sqlfluff_command: "fix" # Or "lint"
          config: "${{ github.workspace }}/.sqlfluff"
          paths: '${{ github.workspace }}/models'
          github_base_ref: "main"     <========================
      - name: 'Show outputs (Optional)'
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo '${{ steps.lint-sql.outputs.sqlfluff-results }}' | jq -r '.'
          echo '${{ steps.lint-sql.outputs.sqlfluff-results-rdjson }}' | jq -r '.'
```

(Do not include the `<======...` part, only the `github_base_ref: "main"`)

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I just updated the question to include the action yml file. I am not sure where to include the your answer in the action file. Isn't it set to `main` by default? Do I have to set it as:
``` on:
          pull_request:
                branches:
                      - main
``` 
in the yml file?

Comment: @G1124E Add  `github_base_ref` set to `main` in your parameters, for testing.

Comment: I am just learning github actions by following the example in for a project I'm working where I need to create to push sql files . I spent quite some time trying to figure this out. Not quite sure where in my file structure I should set the github_base_ref. I added your answer to the yml file under the `run` however, it failed. I was wondering if you can elaborate on where/how in the yml file I can set gthub_base_ref?

Comment: @G1124E I have edited the answer to show how to include that parameter.

Comment: @G1124E Great! Well done.